# Where can I find System.IO to use FileSystemWatcher on Delphi 11?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I need to monitor real time if a new file is created on a folder. System.IO.FileSystemWatcher seems a perfect solution. But on Delphi 11 it is reporting

> [dcc32 Fatal Error] F2613 Unit 'System.IO' not found.

Do I have to download something to have the .pas unit?

P.S. I have explored using the windows API FindFirstChangeNotification but this does not provide the filename created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` is a .net class and not part of the Delphi RTL. Therefore you won't find it anywhere.

I think the API function you need is `ReadDirectoryChangesW`.

Comment: Thank you. Why are there some resources pointing to it like these:
http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Method.asp?NameSpace=System.IO&Class=FileSystemWatcher&Type=Class&Method=WaitForChanged and this
https://www.delphipower.xyz/dotnet_2/listing_filesystemwatcher_example.html

Anyways, thanks! I will try to check out ReadDirectoryChangesW

Comment: @deggen because those resources refer to the long abandoned delphi .net compliler

Comment: I found sample code using the ReadDirectoryChangesW function: https://github.com/bero/DirMonitorDemo

Answer (score 0):

You can also use DDNRuntime(Delphi .NET Framework/.NET Core Runtime)

https://github.com/ying32/DDNRuntime-examples

It can help you call .net fuctions easyly

Just like

```pascal
procedure TestMemoryStream;
var
  LMem: DNMemoryStream;
  LBytes: TArray<Byte>;
  B: Byte;
  LReadLen: Integer;
begin
  LMem := TDNMemoryStream.Create;
  
  LMem.Write([1,2,3,4,5], 0, 5);
  LMem.WriteByte(121);
  LMem.Flush;
  LMem.Position := 0;

  Writeln('data Length: ', LMem.Length);
  SetLength(LBytes, LMem.Length);
  LReadLen :=  LMem.Read(LBytes, 0, Length(LBytes));
  Writeln('len: ', LReadLen);
  for b in LBytes do
    Write(b, ' ');
  Writeln;
end;
```